# Regex prevents values ​less than or equal to zero and accepts decimal values

Tags: angular, regex, angular-formbuilder, angular-custom-validators

Hello I'm building a form in Angular with `FormBuilder` and i want to put a validation in `Validators.pattern()` that prevents values ​​less than or equal to zero and that accepts decimal values

How would the regex expression look? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't. Sure, you could use something like `^([1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?|0\.\d+)$`, but you're better off restricting the input in other ways, like `<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="0">` for example.

---

##### Explanation of the regex

First of all, it's anchored between `^` and `$`, so the entire input must be matched. Then, there are two options, separated by `|`:

1. `[1-9]` a digit between 1 and 9
   `\d*` followed by any number of digits
   `(\.\d+)?` optionally followed by a decimal point and at least one digit
2. `0` a zero
   `\.\d+` followed by a decimal point and at least one digit

Note that if it starts with a zero, the decimal point and a following digit are mandatory, while if there's any other leading digit, the decimal point and following digits are optional, although if there *is* a decimal point, there should be at least one digit after that.

Comment: The adjustment solved the problem, thanks for the explanation and the help.